# Node Gui installation can't find Cmake

Tags: node.js, qt, npm, cmake

I'm trying to install nodegui following their docs, but seems it can't find Cmake even if I already installed it (and visual studio 2019 too). This is the error:

```
> cross-env CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=8 cmake-js compile

[
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\Users\\giova\\Coding projects\\Node_Gui\\Tutorial_1\\nodegui-starter\\node_modules\\cmake-js\\bin\\cmake-js',
  'compile'
]
ERR! OMG CMake is not installed. Install CMake.
ERR! OMG CMake is not installed. Install CMake.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @nodegui/nodegui@0.36.0 build:addon: `cross-env CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=8 cmake-js compile`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @nodegui/nodegui@0.36.0 build:addon script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\giova\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-15T06_47_38_675Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @nodegui/nodegui@0.36.0 postinstall: `cross-env npm run setupqt && (node ./scripts/skip.js || npm run build:addon)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @nodegui/nodegui@0.36.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\giova\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-15T06_47_39_666Z-debug.log
```

Comment: When you type `cmake --version` on your terminal does it display the cmake version ?

Comment: yes: cmake version 3.20.6

Comment: I also tried the 3.21, but nothing changes

Answer (score 3):

I think I solved the issue by adding `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin` to the PATH enviroment variable, like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_X5Iq9niDE.
I'm not 100% sure this is the actual solution because I tried random things before that, but probably it's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and installed this package globally: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cmake-js

1. `npm i -g cmake-js`
2. `npm i` on the NodeGui install

This got me beyond the cmake problem.